# What happens when you inherit a protected property backed by private field?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I know it works, but can't seem to wrap my head around what actually happens:

```
public class Base {
  private bool active;
  protected bool Active {
    get { return active; }
    set { active = value; }
  }
}

public class Child : Base {
  // ...
}
```

AFAIK, Child won't inherit `private` fields, and `Child.Active` works.

- Does it mean Child still somehow *inherits the knowledge of this field*?
- Does it work differently (internally) when using Auto Property?

Comment: In child class - when you call Active, the implementation is used from `Base` class, where private field is used. Just like in methods (you can use base methods that uses private fields). Remember, also: property is implemented as two methods, underhood. When you override `Active` you cannot use backfield from base class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Child` class has *all* of the members that the `Base` class declares. Whether it can **directly**<sup>1</sup> access a particular member is what the access modifiers change.

The `Child` class cannot *directly* access `active`, but that doesn't mean it doesn't *have* an `active` field. It's just *inaccessible* to it. And *code* that it inherits from `Base` that accesses that field, whether that code be a property or a method continues to be able to access the field.

If `Child` chooses to *override* `Active`, *that* code still cannot directly *access* the `active` field. But it can indirectly make changes to the field by making use of the `base.Active` property from within the override.

---

<sup>1</sup>Insert all the usual caveats around reflection or other tricks that may allow fully trusted code to make changes to fields that are otherwise "protected" by an access modifier.

Comment: You are right, I was having a brief moment of confusion on how inheritance actually works...

Answer (score 1):

'protected' hasn't moved `Active` into Child in any way, it's just made it accessible to `Child`.  So `Child` can call `Active` and the contents of `Active` can see the field value.

Auto properties work the same way.